# Using custom font for iOS app on storyboards or xib files

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

> I've got font guideline for my app. Font is custom and i know how to
>   use custom font for iOS app.

[image]

I have a theme class in which i have defined all these fonts like following

```
struct Theme {
  static func getH4Font()  -> UIFont {
        return UIFont.init(name: "NeuePlakText-SemiBold", size: 14.0)!
    }
}
```

> To apply this font to any label i need to drag its **IBOUTLET** and set
>   the font accordingly but i am wondering if there is any way to set
>   these fonts directly via stroyboards or xib files. Like how come i can directly access these "H1,H2,H3" predefined fonts in
>   storyboards or xib files.
>
> > *I don't want to select the custom font,weight & size for each label again and again. Any help would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by creating subclass of UILabel and the following is the example that can help you.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel
{
    @IBInspectable var textFont:Int = 0

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeLabel()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeLabel()
    }

    func initializeLabel()
    {
       self.font = FontType.getFont(rawValue: textFont)
    }
}

enum FontType: Int
{
    case Default = 0, Small, Large

    var fount: UIFont
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .Default:
                return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
            case .Small:
                return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80)
            case .Large:
                return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)
        }
    }

    static func getFont(rawValue: Int) -> UIFont
    {
        if let fontType = FontType(rawValue: rawValue)
        {
            return fontType.fount
        }
        return FontType.Default.fount
    }
}
```

Also, you will need to set the property on XIB/Storyboard:

[image]

[image]

I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thankyou sharma. I already know this solution but it's not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there’s no way to set custom styles on Interface Builder, but what you could do is to subclass UILabel for each style and have that subclass apply the style to itself.

You could also create a subclass that takes a string parameter using IBInspectable so you can set it from Interface Builder and use that parameter to set the style.

[Stylish](https://github.com/daniel-hall/Stylish) does something like that.